# How can I count the number of listview rows with the same value?

Tags: android, listview

I built a ListView that gets bigger everytime that a user clicks at a button, and I would like to put a limit on the user, and allow only 4 rows per day.

Thats why I'm trying to count the number of rows with a specific value (Date), and get the exact value from the listview rows that were created at the current day, to prevent the user from add more rows.

I'm getting my data from Json:

```
try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String date = c.getString(TAG_DATE);

                        HashMap < String, String > contact = new HashMap < String, String > ();

                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                        contactList.add(contact);

                    }
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your for loop, Create SimpleDateFormat instance, depending on date format in your json, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/");
```

Then get current date:

```
String currentDate = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Then count number of rows for current date inside loop:

```
if (date.equals(currentDate)) {
    count++;
}
```

After exiting for loop:

```
// number of rows user allowed to add today
int allowed = LIMIT - count;
```